# Work with Sun Solaris Operating System from .Net Based Application

Tags: asp.net, solaris

I am having a very strange requirement, Our client is having one network management system (Netcool) which reads the number of machine from two text file.

Now whenever new machine is added in those text files application needs restart.

We need to develop one GUI which writes the new machine into network in those files and restart the said application.

I was in favor of java based application for the same but here everybody wants solution in ASP .Net

Now i am not sure is it possible to write file on sun solaris based operating system from .net application and then restarting the process which is running on the same machine.

Please suggest me, it would be great if you are having any articles or examples for the same.

Comment: Finally i am able to convince that we should go ahead with java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Investigate mono. this can help you.

http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page

http://204.152.191.100/wiki/index.php/How_to_build_Mono_on_Solaris

Comment: have you found some solution?

Comment: http://forums.asp.net/p/1496526/3530365.aspx#3530365 : got this answer from another forum.

But due to time limitation and other parameters we have decided to go ahead with Java

Never the less thanks for your effort.

Answer (score 0):

You can get Netcool to run a script on when the alarm comes in.